# Software for moving files and leaving shortcuts

Tags: robocopy

i want to move files from my server to another server. This is working fine with robocopy but now i want to leave a shortcut in the old source directory with the same name like the moved file pointing to the new destination. I dont want my users to search files on both servers.

Hope all is clear. Can you help me with this problem?
Thanks
Andreas

---

I dont know if that was clear. I want to move files (older than 3 years) from Server A to Server B so that Server A saves disks space. The employees shouldnt notice anything cause the see the same files as usual but in reality the files are located on Server B. These are 1000s of files. 
So the process should be:
Move file (older that 3 years) from A to B and create a shortcut on A point to B automatically. User shouldnt notice where file is located.
Thanks 
Andreas

Comment: Hi Andreas, you might want to state what you've tried and ask specific question about the error you've encountered. The following might get you started "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701840/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-powershell" and "http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_create_shortcut.htm"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a shortcut via GUI, you can right click the item, drag it to the destination and select create shortcut.  But I'm looking for a way to do this for a lot of files and folders.  A utility or a script.  Anyone run across anything with that capability?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/525581)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to right click on the folder (in the new destination) and make shortcut to your desktop and after copy the shortcut to the old source ?

I think, if you make that by pointing the new share by his complete path (ex : \192.168.1.1\Files_Share) it will be able to work.